# If entered an even number of integers in bubble sort program a random number is inserted in the middle

Tags: c, sorting, swap

I have a task to sort negative and positive numbers while using dynamic memory, therefore in this case I used calloc and bubble sort to arrange negative numbers first while not changing their order. The problem is when I enter an even number of integers, in the middle of the result some random negative number of 10 digits appears. The same doesn't happen with odd number of integers. What seems to be the problem?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define SIZE 1000

void swap(int *arr, int n) {
    int i, j, temp;
    for (i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
        for (j = 1; j <= n; j++) {
            if (arr[j] < 0) {
                temp = arr[j];
                arr[j] = arr[j - 1];
                arr[j - 1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("sorted integers to negative and positive: \n");
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("%i ", arr[i]);
    }
}

int main() {
    int n;
    int i, *sk;
    printf("Enter integer: \n");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    printf("Enter %i integers: \n", n);
    sk = (int*)calloc(sizeof(int), n);
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        scanf("%d", sk + i);
    }
    swap(sk, n);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you used a debugger and/or even basic debug print statements to trace the execution of your program? That's the standard ways of debugging problems in code (with a post to Stackoverflow only if all debugging efforts fail).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 classic bugs in your `for` loops:

`for (i = 0; i <= n; i++)` is almost always wrong because the loop is run `n + 1` times, where it should only enumerate index values from `0` to `n - 1`.

You have the same off by one error in the second loop: the test `j <= n` makes you go one step too far and read beyond the end of the array.  Some random value gets shuffled into the array, but this undefined behavior could have worse consequences.

Furthermore, your comparison test is incorrect, it should be `if (arr[j] < arr[j-1])`.

As a rule of thumb, whenever you see the `<=` operator in a loop test, look again, it is probably a bug.

Here is a corrected version:

```
void swap(int *arr, int n) {
    int i, j, temp;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (j = 1; j < n; j++) {
            if (arr[j] < arr[j - 1]) {
                temp = arr[j];
                arr[j] = arr[j - 1];
                arr[j - 1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("sorted integers to negative and positive: \n");
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("%i ", arr[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is undefined behavior that happens to manifest itself to you only when you happen to enter an even number of integers, but in reality the problem is always there: you read a value from one-past-the-end of the array, and it makes its way to the middle of your array.

You can fix this behavior by changing `i <= n` and `j <= n` with `i < n` and `j < n`. However, this is not going to fix your broken sorting algorithm, because the swapping condition is incorrect as well. Instead of

```
if(arr[j]<0)
```

it should be

```
if(arr[j]<arr[j-1])
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer, changing <= to < in for loop helped to solve the main problem, although changing if statement sorted the numbers but negatives were in inclining order while positive were sorted in the order as it was entered. Anyways, I'll SORT this one out on my own, thanks for the tips :)

Comment: @Žilvinas: I'm puzzled by your remark on the sorting order issue: can you post actual input and output?

Comment: Enter integer:
8
Enter 8 integers:
-5
6
-9
10
-6
55
-2
-6
sorted integers to negative and positive:
-9 -6 -6 -5 -2 6 10 55

OK, I probably accidentally put the positive numbers like that, but anyways, all of them are sorted in inclining order nevertheless